# Saving routes from ArcGIS Network Analyst between set of points as shapefile in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst

Does anybody know how to  save the routes from ArcGIS Network Analyst between set of points as a shapefile in ArcGIS?